# Php интерпритатор

Tags: php

Доброе утро :-)

Народ, помогайте.
Нужно как-то собрать Standalone php интерпритатор.
Как правило, на debian устанавливают php путем apt-get install, а мне нужно собрать из сорцев php таким образом, чтобы можно было копипастом переносить его с машины на машину и свободно запускать без установки.

У кого-нить было нечто подобное ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отличненько :-) Связал php и Java сервер двухсторонне. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Копипастом? Не выйдет, интерпритатор большой слишком  - в буфер не влезет.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/statically-compile-php-not-possible-then-860677/